# How to leave endless loop by signal?

Tags: c, signals

If I have something like this.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signalquit(int sig)
{
   printf("\nQuitting..\n");
   (void)signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
   //How to return?
}

int main(void)
{
   (void)signal(SIGINT, signalquit);
   while (1)
   {
      //Something...
   }
   //Continue here after quit with "Control + C"
   return 0;
}
```

How can I return to my main function after the while loop and after quitting with Control + C? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can't use `printf` in a signal handler. `printf` has internal state such that if you are in the `printf` function when the signal arrives, calling `printf` again in the signal handler will corrupt it.

Answer (score 5):

> How to leave endless loop by signal?

By flagging that your are done.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_XXX macros */
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

void signalquit(int sig)
{
  flag = 1;

  signal(sig, SIG_DFL);

  return; /* Optional for void-functions */
}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGINT, signalquit);

  while (!flag)
  {
    //Something...
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note that not every function may be called from a signal handler. `printf()` for example is not guaranteed to by async-signal-safe.

To find a  list of functions to be guaranteed by POSIX to be async-signal-safe [scroll down here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html).

---

Your code uses the `signal()` function, which for historical reason is highly unportable.

A portable approach would use the [function `sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) like for example below:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_XXX macros */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

int set_sig_handler(int sig, void(*handler)(int))
{
  struct sigaction sa = {0};
  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  return sigaction(sig, sa, NULL);
}

void signalquit(int sig)
{
  flag = 1;

  if (-1 == set_sig_handler(sig, SIG_DFL))
  {
    flag = 2;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  if (-1 == set_sig_handler(SIGINT, signalquit))
  {
    perror("set_sig_handler() failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while (!flag)
  {
    //Something...
  }

  if (2 == flag)
  {
    perror("set_sig_handler() in signal handler failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

[As pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116259/how-to-leave-endless-loop-by-signal/48116303?noredirect=1#comment83210805_48116303) by [*pilcrow*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132382/pilcrow) an even simpler approach is to explicitly install the handler for single use only by specifying the `SA_RESETHAND` flag.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_XXX macros */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

void signalquit(int sig)
{
  flag = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  {
    struct sigaction sa = {0};

    sa.sa_handler = signalquit;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;

    if (-1 == sigaction(SIGINT, sa, NULL))
    {
      perror("sigaction() failed");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  while (!flag)
  {
    //Something...
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How about setting SA_RESETHAND and not worrying about explicitly resetting the signal handler?  That might be a welcome simplification if the OP truly does want a second SIGINT to be fatal.